# Javascript select element to string comparison

Tags: javascript

Below Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select name="cars" id="demo1">
<option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="Car">Car</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var compare = 'Volvo';
        var e = document.getElementById("demo1");
        var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if (val == compare) {
            alert(val);
        }
     }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above, if I select 'Volvo' from the list and click on "Try it" button it should compare the selected value(here the value is "Volvo") with "Volvo" in javascript and alert the selected value but the "IF" condition in javascript always fails.

Can anyone spot the bug in the code?

Thanks,
ADI

Comment: try to `console.log(val)` before the comparison

Comment: Your function as posted is missing a closing `}` - have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: @Pointy The function works as intended when the closing brace is added.

Comment: Works just fine with the syntax error fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/eezek154/.

Comment: Also, `value` is stored in the `SELECT` element, so you do `e.value`

Comment: You've literally just forgotten to close the function

Answer (score 1):

Just insert a closed curly bracket at the end of `myFunction`

```
function myFunction() {
    var compare = 'Volvo';
    var e = document.getElementById("demo1");
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (val == compare) {
        alert(val);
    }
}
```